# How do I adjust custom xticklabel location on Seaborn Barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am currently using seaborn to create a basic barplot. Initially, I have xtick labels of 1 through 10:

[image]

However, I would like to remove the xtick labels of 1 through 10 and simply replace them with "Least Productive, Average, and Most Productive". I have currently tried the following:

```
ax.set(xticklabels=['Least Productive','Average','Most Productive'])
```

However, I get the following:

[image]

Really, I just need "Least Productive" on the left most side, "Average" in the middle and "Most Productive" on the right-hand side.

I will not always have exactly values 1 through 10 as occasionally in my data set I may be missing any of these values so I cannot reference 1 to Least Productive, 10 to Most Productive etc.

Thank you in advance.

Edit, current code as is:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

ax = sns.barplot(x='Rank', y='Yld_Vol_Dr', data=df, color=sns.xkcd_rgb["grass green"])

sns.despine()
ax.set(ylim=(min(df.Yld_Vol_Dr)*0.9,max(df.Yld_Vol_Dr)*1.1))
ax.set(xticklabels=['Least Productive','Average','Most Productive'])

plt.xlabel('HD Productivity',fontsize=25)
plt.ylabel('Yield (bu/ac)',fontsize=25)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=15)
```

Comment: What is middle for you? 5 or 6? Also, you haven't provided any code which we can run and provide you an answer

Comment: In this case, not an exact number, but average would range between something like 4-7. I added an edit providing my additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a list of blank labels and then replace the first, the last, and a middle value with your labels. Here's for example how it would work with seaborn's tips dataset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax = sns.barplot(x='size', y='tip', data=df, color=sns.xkcd_rgb["grass green"])
sns.despine()

n = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
labels = ['' for i in range(n)]
labels[0] = 'Least Productive'
labels[n // 2] = 'Average'
labels[-1] = 'Most Productive'
ax.set(xticklabels=labels)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=15)
```

[image: sparse labels plot example]